# Passing a variable to CSS via selector

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to convey to CSS a selector with a certain value that css then uses as a variable? e.g.

```
-- HTML --    
<div class-name="div-3"></div>

-- CSS --
.div-(x) {
  width: 100px * x;
}
```

Comment: CSS has no such feature.  You can approximate it with LESS or SASS parameterized mixins.

Comment: people need to understand one day that CSS is used for CSS ... it's not a programming langage, so why you want to do everything with CSS ? Use JS for such things or like @SLaks said, use LESS or SASS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

But commonly a preprocessor such as [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) (and Less and Stylus, ...) is used to help with this sort of use case. In Sass you could [loop](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#while) through numbers `x` in a realistic range and generate the rulesets for each. It would output CSS which would explicitly state each rule (`.div-1 {...}`, `.div-2 {...}`, etc).

In future you will be able to do something similar to what you want with plain CSS, however, thanks to the [`attr` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr). You wouldn't be able to add the number to the class itself, I think, but could have it in a `data-width` attribute or similar. But at present the `attr` function is only helpful in the `content` property, which is not useful to you here.